# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'models' imported from

Tags: javascript, node.js, vscode-jsconfig

I'm trying to configure my project to use absolute imports, so I have configured `jsconfig.json` as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
       "baseUrl": "./src",
       "module": "commonjs",
       "target": "es2016"
    },
   "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

but when I try to do an import like `import { Account } from "models";` I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'models' imported from...
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The `jsconfig.json` file is used by VSCode's language server for static JavaScript analysis, it is not read by Node.js and therefore doesn't affect module loading in any way.

Options which come to mind are to use a transpiler, for example tsc, to transpile JS files (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110622/240963)), or use [native ESM support in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/esm.html) possibly with [custom loader](https://github.com/node-loader/node-loader-core). Mind that by default ESM imports expect full filename, including file extension (omitting file extensions in ESM is TypeScript specific quirk).